# building android filesystem

Tags: java, android

while building android filesystem, i am getting an error as

```
You are attempting to build with the incorrect version
of javac.

Your version is: javac 1.7.0_12-ea.
The correct version is: 1.6.

Please follow the machine setup instructions at
    http://source.android.com/source/download.html
```

but i am having the version of 1.6 only.

```
$ java -version 
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

actually i was having java 1.7, then after seeing this error i just installed java 1.6 amd removed java 1.7. but till now it is pointing to java 1.7. What will i do hereafter
? please guide me. Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following command and changed the version needed:

```
do following:

sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This command will display all versions of java you have.

It will ask selection number as following:

```
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

type the version what u want.

It is used to rectify my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [update-java-alternatives](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-java-alternatives.8.html).